# API is sending no data when calling from another project & showing HTTP error 204

Tags: asp.net, angular, fiddler

I have a method in an ASP.net API, which sends JWT token when it gets a Request with HTTP Get Method. On fiddler when I call this API, everything works fine; but when I call same API with another project (made in angular 8) I get HTTP 204 Error and no data.
In Angular Project I call this API on NgOnInit of my Component.

Here is code of API

```
  [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public string GetToken()
        {
            try
            {
                string key = "FIPL@321456222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"; //Secret key which will be used later during validation    
                var issuer = "http://localhost:1424/";  //normally this will be your site URL    

                var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                //Create a List of Claims, Keep claims name short    
                var permClaims = new List<Claim>();
                permClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
                //permClaims.Add(new Claim("valid", "1"));
                //permClaims.Add(new Claim("userid", "1"));
                //permClaims.Add(new Claim("name", "bilal"));

                //Create Security Token object by giving required parameters    
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, //Issure    
                                issuer,  //Audience    
                                         permClaims,
                                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                                signingCredentials: credentials);
                var jwt_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
                enter image description here
                return (String)jwt_token;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (string)ex.Message ;
            }

        }
```

Here is code of angular where API is called.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Auth"));
    this.DepartmentModel._iBPNo = obj.BPNo;
    this.DepartmentModel._iLoginNo = obj.LoginNo;
    //Here I am Calling the API to get token
    this.httpServices.get("http://localhost:52484/api/Token/gettoken/", null, (data) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      localStorage.setItem("Token", JSON.stringify(data));
      
         }, (error) => {
           console.log(error);
      });


    if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("PDEP"))) {
      this.DeptNo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("PDEP"));
      this.LoadData();
    }
  }
```

Here is link to my fiddler Page Response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try subscribing to an HTTP request directly :

```
this.httpServices.get("http://localhost:52484/api/Token/gettoken").subscribe((data) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      localStorage.setItem("Token", JSON.stringify(data));
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```